# Call C++ APIs from Javafx UI for a desktop application

Tags: c++, javafx

I am interested in using Javafx for my visual content for a desktop application and call native,unmanaged C++ functions ( on events from the Javafx views). Is this possible? Can someone explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

As JavaFX has been designed for maximal compatibility with the Java platform, you can always call Java code from your JavaFX code, and then do some JNI stuff, as in [this example question](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5393510).